# How can I remove specific character in the output of my curl

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
curl http://localhost:8080/api/examples-services/postcode/Sydney | json_pp | grep -E '"' | cut -d \  -f7,8,9,10 | tr -d '",:,'
```

[image: My output]

What I'd want to do is to remove the numbers and the NSW in that output.
And also if there's a proper way to do that, I don't think my code is the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sed`'s substitute command (`s`).

Piping your output to this command will get read of all your `NSW`:

```
sed 's/NSW//'
```

`sed`'s substitute command works like this: `s/regexp/replacement/flags`. So here, on each line, we are replacing `NSW` by nothing (without any flag).

Also, if you have multiple `NSW` per line that you want to remove, you can use the `g` (global) flag:

```
sed 's/NSW//g'
```

[More information about `sed`'s substitute command.](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html)

Comment: Hi thankyou for answering my question,
It help but I forgot that I also want to remove the numbers.

Comment: curl http://localhost:8080/api/examples-services/postcode/Sydney | json_pp | grep -E '"' | cut -d \  -f7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14

and the output is
"North Sydney Shoppingworld" : "NSW 2060"
What I've wanted to do is delete  ( : "NSW 2060" )

Comment: Again using `sed` and a regex, you can get rid of all the digits with this command: `sed 's/[0-9]//'g`.

Comment: but what I need sir is to remove the : to "
curl -s http://localhost:8080/api/examples-services/postcoE '"' | cut -d \  -f7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14 | sed 's/[:-,]//'g

and the output is sed: 1: "s/[:-,]//g": RE error: invalid character range

Comment: `.curl -s http://localhost:8080/api/examples-services/postcode/Sydney | json_pp | grep -E '"' | cut -d \  -f7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14 | sed '1d' | tr -d '",:' | sed 's/[0-9]//'g | sed 's/NSW//g' ` 

this would work but if I entered another city. It would messed up
so what I've needed is to print a specific character column range

Comment: @IanJayloGuinto You can get an optimal solution if you post example input and expected output :)